# How to exclude a class from scanning with CDI 1.0

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, weblogic12c, weld

I would like to exclude a class from scanning in CDI 1.0. I'm using the default implementation of CDI in WebLogic 12.1.12 (Weld, CDI 1.0).

I saw several web sites and docs with CDI 1.1 but not with the previous release .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With Weld, you can use a custom XML namespace in `beans.xml` to exclude classes from scanning:

```
 <beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:weld="http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans">
   <weld:scan>
     <weld:exclude name="com.acme.swing.**"/>
   </weld:scan>
 </beans>
```

See the [Weld Manual](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.16.Final/en-US/html_single/#d0e5774) for details.

Comment: You referenced the version 1.1.16 of weld. Can I use the same configuration with weld 1.0.xx ?

Answer (score 2):

I once had this problem and failed to find a standard solution in CDI 1.0.
There's a workaround though: mark a bean with `@Alternative` and don't select this alternative in beans.xml (that is don't list it in `<alternatives>` element). It should do the trick.
Also in CDI 1.1 they filled this gap with scan/exclude element.

Answer (score 2):

If `@Vetoed` (available since CDI 1.1) would work for you, you can use `@Typed()` without values or with Apache DeltaSpike `@Exclude`.
If you can't(/don't like to)change the class, you can create a CDI-Extension and observer `ProcessAnnotatedType` -> call #veto if e.g. `processAnnotatedType.getAnnotatedType().getJavaClass()` returns the class you would like to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and as @Yuri said, You can achieve it using the @Alternative annotation if You can modify the class, but if You can't (e.g. it is a third party library), then You can't control it.

If You check the xsd of cd 1.0 (http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd), You won't find a tag, which could help You.

BTW there is WebLogic 12.1.1 and there is 12.1.2, but there is no WebLogic 12.1.12. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_WebLogic_Server#Application_Server_versions)