# How to create a configurable CDI Producer?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I have **two beans** that implement an **interface**:

```
@Storage(StorageType.LOCAL)
public class LocalStorage implements StorageService { 
    // [...]
}
```

and

```
@Storage(StorageType.REMOTE)
public class RemoteStorage implements StorageService { 
    // [...]
}
```

In a service class I am using an **injected StorageService**:

```
@Stateless
public class DocumentService {

    @Inject
    @Storage(StorageType.REMOTE)
    private StorageService storageService;

    // [...]
```

}

This works well, but **I would like to be able to configure the StorageType from outside**, without changing the sourcecode.

So I created a Producer:

```
@Singleton
public class StorageServiceProducer {

    @Inject
    @ConfigurationValue("storage.type") // Injects values from a properties file
    private String storageType;

    @Produces
    public StorageService produceStorageService(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {            
        if (storageType.equals("remote")) {
            return new RemoteStorage();
        } else {
            return new LocalStorage();
        }
    }
}
```

...and removed the @Storage annotation from my beans:

```
public class LocalStorage implements StorageService { 
    // [...]
}
```

and

```
public class RemoteStorage implements StorageService { 
    // [...]
}
```

But now I am getting an **ambiguous dependencies exception**, presumably because of the presence of the producer itself. In order to force the usage of the producer, I found that I can use the "@Vetoed" annotation.

This seems to work, **but since the bean is no longer managed, any injected value in my implementations are missing**:

```
public class RemoteStorage implements StorageService {

    @Inject
    @ConfigurationValue("project.id")
    private String projectId;

    // [...]

}
```

So here are my questions:

- Is this the right way to have a **"dynamic" producer** that can be configured ?
- I succeeded with using @Alternatives, but this has the same drawbacks as the Annotation approach: if I want to change the implementation, I need to change the beans.xml file
- How can I achieve this ?

Edit: I am using CDI 1.2 and bean-discovery-mode="all"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a right approach towards dynamic producer but note that CDI is, in general, quite static so trying to do stuff dynamically might not always feel smooth. 
Now, what you are bumping in is that you create the instances yourself (using `new`), hence CDI only knows the resulting object and doesn't have control over it. E.g. it won't inject into fields/constructor/.. of your impl beans.

There two options I can think of from the top of my head:

1. **Operate on bean-only base**

This means you won't create the beans yourself and your producer will merely hand over the correct bean. The bright side of this approach is that CDI handles it all, hence your injections will work without any additional effort. Also, interception, decoration, event handlers etc. will all work as you would expect. The not-so-bright side is if you have more implementations or are going to add more as time passes, then this gets messy.

To achieve this, you can (for instance) limit the **type set of your implementations** so that they do not fit when you `@Inject StorageService`.

```
@Typed({Object.class, RemoteStorage.class})
public class RemoteStorage implements StorageService { ....}
```

And do likewise for the other storage implementation.
Then, from your producer, you can do something like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class StorageServiceProducer {

@Inject
@ConfigurationValue("storage.type") // Injects values from a properties file
private String storageType;

// there should be no ambiguity injecting specific impl type
@Inject
RemoteStorage remoteStorage;

@Inject
LocalStorage localStorage;

@Produces
public StorageService produceStorageService(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {            
    if (storageType.equals("remote")) {
        return remoteStorage;
    } else {
        return localStorage;
    }
}
```

}

2. **Create objects yourself and manually ensure injection works**

In this approach we keep your code as-is, only adding a snippet which will inject into resulting instances. The upside is that it's probably easier to extend and quite straightforward. The downside is that you do not get a full-blown CDI bean, you are just handing an instance to CDI saying "*Hey, if someone asks for a bean of type 'StorageService', you give him this, oh and please inject into it.*" Interception, decoration, observers and other stuff isn't going to work there. To be more precise you will simply turn that instance in what CDI calls `InjectionTarget`.

Here is how:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class StorageServiceProducer {

@Inject
@ConfigurationValue("storage.type") // Injects values from a properties file
private String storageType;

@Inject
BeanManager bm;

@Produces
public StorageService produceStorageService(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {          
    StorageService result = null;  
    if (storageType.equals("remote")) {
        result = RemoteStorage();
    } else {
        result = LocalStorage();
    }
    // make it an injection target, it's gonna be something like this
    CreationalContext<Object> ctx = bm.createCreationalContext(null);
    InjectionTarget<Object> injectionTarget = (InjectionTarget<Object>) beanManager
        .getInjectionTargetFactory(bm.createAnnotatedType(result.getClass())).createInjectionTarget(null);
    injectionTarget.inject(result, ctx);

    // return result which was injected into
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: I had tried your first solution, but I did not know about the @Typed annotation and without it I was getting an ambiguous dependency exception. So that was missing. I only have 2 implementations, so the first solution is not messy. Thank you !

Comment: You could also combine your first and second approach by using the typed annotation and then create the bean via CDI.current().select(RemoteStorage.class).get() or CDI.current().select(LocalStorage.class).get(). This way, you avoid the hassle of calling up the injection manually.

Comment: That's right, you could do that too. My list of far from complete but should suffice for OP's case.

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution is to use @New qualifier.

First You need to exclude both beans implementation from auto discovery. Not sure which version of CDI You are running - from 1.1 You can use @Vetoed annotation. Or use beans.xml for this like in this answer: [How to exclude a class from scanning with CDI 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405886/how-to-exclude-a-class-from-scanning-with-cdi-1-0) (although it's Weld specific)

```
@Vetoed
public class LocalStorage implements StorageService { 
// [...]
}

@Vetoed
public class RemoteStorage implements StorageService { 
    // [...]
}
```

Then You inject both implementation into producer method using @New qualifier:

```
@Singleton
public class StorageServiceProducer {

    @Inject
    @ConfigurationValue("storage.type") // Injects values from a properties file
    private String storageType;

    @Produces
    public StorageService produceStorageService(@New LocalStorage localStorage, @New RemoteStorage remoteStorage) {            
        if (storageType.equals("remote")) {
            return remoteStorage;
        } else {
            return localStorage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `@New` has been deprecated long ago and was replaced by `@Dependent` - I strongly advise against `@New`. OP's beans and producer are already dependent by definition.

Comment: I'm sill on CDI 1.0 :) But '@Dependent' was there from the beginning alongside '@New'.

Comment: Also not sure what You mean that producers are dependent by default? If You do not put any scope definition on a producer then that's true.

Comment: I am using CDI 1.2. I will try the solution proposed by @Siliarus. I will then read about the '@New' being deprecated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use your two `Storage` implementations, as you do now, but remove the qualifiers and type them very explicitly to exclude `StorageService` (this also assumes they've been added to the CDI system as enabled beans via one mechanism or another, which would happen, for example, if they were also annotated with a [bean-defining annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#bean_defining_annotations) or [programmatically added by an extension](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/2.0/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeforeBeanDiscovery.html#addAnnotatedType-javax.enterprise.inject.spi.AnnotatedType-)):

```
@Typed(LocalStorage.class)
public class LocalStorage implements StorageService { 
    // [...]
}

@Typed(RemoteStorage.class)
public class RemoteStorage implements StorageService { 
    // [...]
}
```

Next, make them be injected dependencies of your producer method:

```
@Produces
public StorageService produceStorageService(LocalStorage localStorage, RemoteStorage remoteStorage) {            
    if (storageType.equals("remote")) {
        return remoteStorage;
    } else {
        return localStorage;
    }
}
```